# A function just skips execution when called - no debugger error though

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I debugged the code and when the program reaches this line of code (of a bigger function)...

```
login_result = login(driver)
```

...it skips to the next line(no error or anything)

I tried just running it but the same outcome is outputted.

Here is the `login()` function:

```
def login(driver):

    # Check if logged in (or login failed)
    login_result = 1
    login_check_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
    for login_check in login_check_elements:
        if(login_check.text == "Log in" and login_check.is_enabled()):
            # If there is a login button on the screen and the button is enabled by default it means
            # that the driver is on the account page and is not logged in
            login_result = 0

    # If login failed - return 1
    if(login_result == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        username, password = find_input_elements(driver)
        username.send_keys("username")
        time.sleep(randint(1, 3))
        password.send_keys("password")
        time.sleep(randint(1, 3))
        login_button = find_login_button(driver)
        login_button.click()
        return 0
```

*EDIT: I forgot to say that, yes, I have included breaking points on almost every line in the function, including the first one.

Comment: just-in-time debugging has always been weird to me so breakpoints in scripting languages have always caused me issues. I assume you've also just tossed a print out into the function to make sure it isn't an issue with your debugger?

Comment: Yeah, the login_result changes. So that must be it. Didn't think this debugger would be such a mess. Do you have any suggestions on a good debugger?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Python has it's own [debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) baked in and that's probably your most reliable bet but it's a bit of a struggle to work with

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the line that is checking for elements does not have any in its list.

```
for login_check in login_check_elements:
```

Try running the code again, and checking what the value of login_result is

```
def login(driver):

# Check if logged in (or login failed)
login_result = 1
login_check_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
for login_check in login_check_elements:
    print('element found')
    if(login_check.text == "Log in" and login_check.is_enabled()):
        # If there is a login button on the screen and the button is enabled by default it means
        # that the driver is on the account page and is not logged in
        login_result = 0

# If login failed - return 1
if(login_result == 1):
    return 1
else:
    username, password = find_input_elements(driver)
    username.send_keys("username")
    time.sleep(randint(1, 3))
    password.send_keys("password")
    time.sleep(randint(1, 3))
    login_button = find_login_button(driver)
    login_button.click()
    return 0

login_result = login(driver)
print(login_result)
```

Most likely by setting the login_result to 1 at the top, it is never finding elements, and going right to the return 1

Comment: Yes, there was an issue with the condition too, but the main problem was from the debugger. It skipped the execution of the function although I have created breaking points inside it. I have fixed the if statement and now it runs as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Rares-AdrianMosescu I see, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not give the solution you are looking for but I will take a stab at it. You have not stated what check is done after you get the return value from the function login_result. If the return value is not asserted, and I guess thats why your code just moves on with the execution. And there is no exception raised within the function, it is designed to return and have the user do something with the result

```
def login(driver):

    # Check if logged in (or login failed)
    login_check_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
    for login_check in login_check_elements:
        if login_check.text == "Log in" and login_check.is_enabled():
            # If there is a login button on the screen and the button is enabled by default it means
            # that the driver is on the account page and is not logged in
            return False
    else:
        username, password = find_input_elements(driver)
        username.send_keys("username")
        time.sleep(randint(1, 3))
        password.send_keys("password")
        time.sleep(randint(1, 3))
        login_button = find_login_button(driver)
        login_button.click()
        return True

login_result = login(driver)
if not login_result:
   # Error out or do something
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention it. The return value is handled by an if statement. The problem was from the debugger...it bugged.